# is script autoloading possible in rebol or red-lang?

Tags: rebol, red

Is there a way to do so ? I searched Google but couldn't find any answer, so I guess the answer would be no. Is there anything close ? If not, would it be easy to extend red-lang to do so ?

Comment: Anything is possible with `do` :p what exactly do you mean with script autoloading?

Comment: Startup scripts are already there in all rebol versions, and you can very easily create your own shortcut for red. Unless you meant something else

Comment: Alternatively, did you mean something like live-coding? https://github.com/red/code/blob/master/Showcase/livecode.red

Comment: If you are interested in the [userspace console code](https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c/blob/e6cab210d6355f50b36fe6e15acc1f5859a95c30/src/os/host-console.r#L256) from the active development branch of open source Rebol3 ("Ren-C"), see [start-up scripts](https://github.com/r3n/reboldocs/wiki/User-and-Console#start-up-scripts).  The idea is that the console itself is implemented in Rebol.  If you have questions, [ask in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From  http://www.rebol.com/docs/setup.html

```
Startup Scripts
```

When REBOL starts it will automatically run the rebol.r and user.r files, if they exist.

The system looks for these files first in the current directory (or the directory of the script being run), then in the directory that contains the REBOL executable program.

Note that REBOL/Core runs fine without the rebol.r and user.r files. They simply provide an easy way to include additional code and data on startup, such as your network preferences.

---

If you compile your own Red interpreter you can add an autoloading file, maybe in **console.red** after **system/console/init "Red Console"** and before **system/console/launch** Best advice is to ask on the https://gitter.im/red/help site to ask for help. I guess this was already discussed.

Comment: I'm using rebolview and created user.r with rebol[] print "test" it doesn't seem to load it at startup. Same with rebol.r ?

Comment: If I remember right, you do not have to create yourself by hand. Create it with the desktop and the user settings. Search for user.r in your path.

Comment: ok thanks, using desktop, he created user.r in AppData\Roaming\rebol not in local folder where rebolview is. I would prefer he uses local folder instead though.

Comment: Either the later versions of rebolview had some problems with the home directories or this are some issues with modern Windows versions